# Element of certain order in special linear space.

Tags: finite-groups

What would be the conditions (if any) on the trace of an element in $SL(2,p)$ in order for it to have order 5 ? (assuming $p= \pm1 mod 10$)

For example, any traceless element in $SL(2,p)$ has order 4 (straightforward proof).

Any suggestion or comment is tremendously valuable.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has order $(p-1)p(p+1)$.  So *a priori* we need $5$ to divide $(p-1)p(p+1)$ for an element of order 5 to possibly exist, and by Cauchy's theorem, this is also sufficient.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thank you. I'm aware of this. I guess the reason why I asked the question is to somehow manipulate certain trace property to construct an element of order 5. I also editted the question.

Comment: To have order 5, the eigenvalues must be 5th roots of unity (modulo $p$), in fact must be a primitive 5th root and its inverse, so the trace must be a sum of a primitive 5th root of unity and its inverse. I don't know whether there's any nice way to characterize such numbers.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers my goal was to somehow relate the order of an element in $SL(2,F)$ to its image under the canonical projection onto $PSL(2,F)$. Anyways, I deleted the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $G=\text{SL}(2,F)$ for an arbitrary field $F$. For an element to have order $m$ (coprime to the characteristic of $k$ if this is prime)
its eigenvalues are $\zeta$ and $\zeta^{-1}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive
$m$-th root of unity, that is $\zeta$ is a zero of the $m$-th cyclotomic
polynomial $\Phi_m$. As long as $m\ge3$, the trace $t=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$
must therefore be a root of the "real cyclotomic" polynomial $\Psi_m$.
This isn't an established name or notation, but is the minimal polynomial
for $2\cos(2\pi/m)$ and satisfies
$$\Psi_m(X+X^{-1})=X^{-\phi(m)/2}\Phi_m(X)$$
where $\phi$ is Euler's totient. For example
$$\Psi_5(X+X^{-1})=X^2+X+1+X^{-1}+X^{-2}$$
and so
$$\Psi_5(Y)=Y^2+Y-1.$$

Comment: +1, coming up with the equation $\Psi_m(X+X^{-1})=X^{-\phi(m)/2}\Phi_m(X)$ was very clever!

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at an example. Let $p=11$. The primitive 5th roots (modulo 11) are $3,4,5,9$, where $3$ and $4$ are inverse, and $5$ and $9$ are inverse. So the trace has to be $3+4=7$ or $5+9=3$.

These necessary conditions are also sufficient. If the determinant is $1$ and the trace is $7$, then the eigenvalues must be $3$ and $4$, so the order must be 5; similarly if the trace is 3.

Maybe this will give some idea how to proceed in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is an element of order $5$ in $\DeclareMathOperator{\SL}{SL} \SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and let $m(x)$ be its minimal polynomial.  If $m$ has degree $1$, then $A$ is a scalar matrix hence must be of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
c & 0\\
0 & c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $c$.  But then $c^2 = \det(A) = 1$, so $A$ has order at most $2$, contradiction.  Thus $m$ must have degree $2$, so we can write $m(x) = x^2 + ax + 1$ for some $a$.  Since $A$ satisfies $x^5 - 1$, then we must have that $x^2 + ax + 1$ divides $x^5 - 1$.

First, assume that $x-1 \nmid x^2 + ax + 1$.  Then $x^2 + ax + 1$ divides $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$.  Using division with remainder, we find that
\begin{align*}
x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 &= (x^2 + (1-a)x + a(a-1))m(x) + (-a^3 + a^2 + a)x + (-a^2 + a + 1)
\end{align*}
Thus we must have that $a$ satisfies $a^2 - a - 1 = 0$.  The quadratic equation $t^2 - t - 1$ has discriminant $5$, hence has a solution iff $5$ is a square mod $p$.  Since $(5|p) = (-1)^{p-1} (p|5) = (p|5)$ by quadratic reciprocity and the only squares mod $5$ are $0,1,4$, then we can find such an $a$ iff $p=5$ or $p \equiv 1, 4 \pmod{5}$.
(Here $(\cdot | \cdot)$ denotes the Legendre symbol.)

In this case, then $a = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ so
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & -\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is an element of order $5$.  (This is the companion matrix for $x^2 + ax + 1$ for the two possible values of $a$.  In fact, by uniqueness of rational canonical form, every such matrix must be similar to one of these matrices.)

If $x-1 \mid x^2 + ax + 1$, then $x^2 + ax + 1 = x^2 - 2x + 1$.  Again using polynomial division, we find
$$
x^5 - 1 = (x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 4)(x^2-2x+1) + 5x-5
$$
so we must have $5 = 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e., $p=5$.  (Thus we discover no new primes in this latter case.)  In this case, $a = -2 = 3$ is also equal to $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Thus in all cases, we find that $\operatorname{Tr}(A) = -a = -\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

For instance, for $p=11$ we have $4^2 = 16 = 5$ and
$$
\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{1 \pm 4}{2} = \frac{5}{2}, \, \frac{8}{2} = 8, 4
$$
are the roots of $t^2 - t - 1$.  Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & -4
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & -8
\end{pmatrix}
$$
have order $5$.

Comment: I was reading up to your matrix but then it got deleted. You think it's confusing if you put it there ?

Comment: @Ronma Fixed the mistake and the matrix is back.

Comment: I was gonna ask why would you consider $m(x)$ in the first place but the edit explains it. Thanks !

Comment: Just a very small detail, why can't one have  $m(x) = x^2 +ax +b$, where $b\neq  1$ ?

Comment: @Ronma For a $2\times 2$ matrix the constant term of the characteristic polynomial is the determinant.  Since $A \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, its determinant is $1$.